# ContextMenu IsOpen property is always false

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I have a button with the `ContextMenu` set as follows:

```
<Button
    x:Name="TestButton"
    Click="TestButton_Click">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Sample Menu Item 1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Sample Menu Item 2" />
            <MenuItem Header="Sample Menu Item 3" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This always prints false, even though the contextmenu is currently opened
    System.Console.WriteLine(button.ContextMenu.IsOpen);

    if (sender is Button button)
    {
        button.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
        button.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = button;
        button.ContextMenu.StaysOpen = true;
        button.ContextMenu.IsOpen = !button.ContextMenu.IsOpen; // Doesn't work!
    }
}
```

So I have set the `ContextMenu` to open on a single mouse click and that works, however I would like to toggle `ContextMenu` visiblity on each button click. To do so, I want to use the `IsOpen` property - set it to false if current value is true and vice-versa.

My problem is that even though the `IsOpen` property value is set from `false` to `true` on the first click, it always remains `false` on the second click, like it would never be set.

I assume it's about the losing focus (correct me, if I'm wrong) - so how can I workaround this and keep it flagged as open, until another click occurs?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Regarding naming the ContextMenu - it wont work like that, results are the same as in the current code. I was unsuccessful trying to get it working in pure XAML, hence code behind.

Comment: Because the ContextMenu actually closes before you enter the event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it's about the losing focus ...

Yes, the `ContextMenu`'s `StaysOpen` property doesn't work as you expect. When you click on the `Button`, the `ContextMenu` is indeed closed.

You could workaround this by using a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` that keeps track of when the `ContextMenu` was closed, and then compare the elapsed time with some constant value in your event handler. This should work:

```
private DependencyPropertyDescriptor _dpd;
private DateTime _closeTime;

private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button button)
    {
        button.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
        button.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = button;
        button.ContextMenu.IsOpen = !button.ContextMenu.IsOpen && DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(_closeTime).TotalMilliseconds > 250;

        if (_dpd == null)
        {
            _dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ContextMenu.IsOpenProperty, typeof(ContextMenu));
            _dpd.AddValueChanged(button.ContextMenu, OnContextMenuClosed);
        }
    }
}

private void OnContextMenuClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) => _closeTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private bool _isOpen = false;

private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // This always prints false, even though the contextmenu is currently opened
    //System.Console.WriteLine(button.ContextMenu.IsOpen);

    if (sender is Button button)
    {
        if (_isOpen)
        {
            button.ContextMenu.IsOpen = false;
            _isOpen = false;
        }
        else
        {
            button.ContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
            button.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = button;
            button.ContextMenu.StaysOpen = true;
            _isOpen = true;
            button.ContextMenu.IsOpen = _isOpen;
        }
    }
}
```